Next.js - localization next-intl - remove default language from url
I'm sharing my middleware.ts and i18n.ts.
Its my first time with localization in next.js, I made it work, but now I'm struggling with URL, because I do not wish to have "cs" in default version, and something is adding the "cs" to URL even if I do not type it.
Is there any settings in next-intl to prevent this?
I don't even know where to start, I have tried to remove "cs" from matcher, but I belive that has no effect on "adding cs to URL".
Also tried to add     localeDetection: false, to return value of i18n.ts
So insted of http://localhost:3000/ I get every time http://localhost:3000/cs.
Thank you for any advice.
Middleware.ts
export default createMiddleware({
  // A list of all locales that are supported
  locales: ["cs", "en"],

  // Used when no locale matches
  defaultLocale: "cs",
});

export const config = {
  // Match only internationalized pathnames
  matcher: ["/", "/(cs|en)/:path*"],
};

i18n.ts
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";
import { getRequestConfig } from "next-intl/server";

// Can be imported from a shared config
const locales = ["cs"];

export default getRequestConfig(async ({ locale }) => {
  // Validate that the incoming `locale` parameter is valid
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument, @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  if (!locales.includes(locale as any)) notFound();

  return {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment, @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
    messages: (await import(`/i18n/${locale}.json`)).default,
  };
});


According to the documentation, in the Pages Router, when we placed all the pages in /pages, hiding the default language version from the URL was the standard behavior. Unfortunately, this is not the case in the App Router. I searched for various solutions, but nothing worked, so I simply copied everything from /app/[locale]/ to /app/. It's an ugly solution because we have to maintain all the files twice, but at least it works. It's a shame that Vercel hasn't resolved this yet. Here’s my working code for middleware.ts.
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

import { i18n } from '@/i18n.config';
import { match as matchLocale } from '@formatjs/intl-localematcher';
import Negotiator from 'negotiator';

function getLocale(request: NextRequest): string | undefined {
  const negotiatorHeaders: Record<string, string> = {};
  request.headers.forEach((value, key) => (negotiatorHeaders[key] = value));

  const locales: string[] = i18n.locales;
  const languages = new Negotiator({ headers: negotiatorHeaders }).languages();

  const locale = matchLocale(languages, locales, i18n.defaultLocale);
  return locale;
}

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname;

  if (pathname.startsWith('/en')) {
    const newPathname = pathname.replace(/^\/en/, '');
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(newPathname || '/', request.url));
  }

  const pathnameIsMissingLocale = i18n.locales.every(
    locale => !pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) && pathname !== `/${locale}`
  );

  if (pathnameIsMissingLocale) {
    const locale = getLocale(request);

    if (locale === i18n.defaultLocale) {
      return NextResponse.next();
    }

    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${locale}${pathname}`, request.url));
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico|public|img|fonts).*)',
  ],
};

And here is my i18n.config.ts
export const i18n = {
  defaultLocale: 'en',
  locales: ['en', 'de', 'es', 'fr'],
  localeDetection: false,
} as const

export type Locale = (typeof i18n)['locales'][number];

